# Close parent as well as pop up window

Tags: jquery

Onclicking the link a pop up will open. Firstly, the parent window needs to be closed (parent tab) and then the pop up has to close as well. Below I am pasting the code which I have tried for your conveneience

JQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //initialize the 3 popup css class names - create more if needed
        var matchClass=['popup1','popup2','popup3'];
        //Set your 3 basic sizes and other options for the class names above - create more if needed
        var popup1 = 'width=400,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=20,top=20';
        var popup2 = 'width=800,height=600,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=20,top=20';
        var popup3 = 'width=1000,height=750,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=20,top=20';

        //The pop-up function
        function tfpop(){


                var x = 0;
                var popClass;
                //Cycle through the class names
                while(x < matchClass.length){

                        popClass = "'."+matchClass[x]+"'";
                        //Attach the clicks to the popup classes
                        $(eval(popClass)).click(function() {

                                //Get the destination URL and the class popup specs
                                var popurl = $(this).attr('href');
                                var popupSpecs = $(this).attr('class');
                                //Create a "unique" name for the window using a random number
                                var popupName = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000001);
                                //Opens the pop-up window according to the specified specs
                                newwindow=window.open(popurl,popupName,eval(popupSpecs));
                                return false;
                        });                         
                x++;
                } 


        }

        //Wait until the page loads to call the function
        $(function() {
            tfpop(); 
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<p><a href="/html/popup-example-small.php" class="popup1">css class popup1 (small window: 400x300 pixels)</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your popup, write a JS function which would close the parent window and the popup as well:

```
window.opener.close();
self.close();
```